# Comparing NSDates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compare, nsdate

I have an NSDate object called 'dueDate'. I'm trying to work out how to display if the due date was yesterday or is tomorrow. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if a date is "tomorrow", do something like this.

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];    
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    // set tomorrow (0: today, -1: yesterday)
    [comps setDay:1];
    NSDate *dateTomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps 
                                                     toDate:currentDate  
                                                    options:0];
    [comps release];
```

The rest should be fairly obvious.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval dateTime;


if ([visitDate isEqualToDate:today])   //visitDate is a NSDate

{

NSLog (@"Dates are equal");

}

dateTime = ([visitDate timeIntervalSinceDate:today] / 86400);  

if(dateTime < 0) //Check if visit date is a past date, dateTime returns - val

{

NSLog (@"Past Date");

}

else 

{   
NSLog (@"Future Date");

}
```

Comment: "isEqualToDate:" is an EXACT match. ie: sub-second match. this test will probably never be TRUE.